# How can I repeat a ListView item a certain number of times using Android and SQLite data and changing one column each iteration?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to repeat certain data from a table in a ListView with one row changing each iteration of the item. I want to have a user input an int of the times to repeat and press a button to update the list.

I am working with dates as the updating item. So if a user inputs '3', I want  3 rows added to the list, and inserted into the table, adding 1 month to the date for the 3 months.

**Main Activity**

```
planAheadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (planAheadMonths.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Add months to plan by", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                int plan = Integer.parseInt(planAheadMonths.getText().toString());
                mDBHelper.updateCheckingPlanner(plan, mChecking.getCheckingId());
                planAheadMonths.setText("");
                mDBHelper.getTransRepeater(plan, mChecking.getCheckingId());

            }

        }
    });
```

**DBHelper**

```
    public void getTransactionRepeater(int repeat, int id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = TRANSACTION_DATE + " BETWEEN " + getCurrentMonth() + " AND " + getFutureMonth() + " AND " +
            TRANSACTION_CHECKING_ID + " = " + id + " AND " + TRANSACTION_REPEAT + " != 'NONE' ";
    String[] whereargs = new String[1];
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS, null, whereclause, null, null, null, TRANSACTION_DATE + " ASC, " + TRANSACTION_ID);
    db.beginTransaction();

    while (res.moveToNext()) {



        if (res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_REPEAT)).equals("MONTH")) {

            for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
                + i);
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_NAME, res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_NAME)));
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_TYPE, res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_TYPE)));
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_DATE, sdf.format(cFuture.getTime()) + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_NAME)) + i);
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)));
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_NOTES, res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_NOTES)));
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_REPEAT, res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_REPEAT)));
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_CHECKING_ID, res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_CHECKING_ID)));
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_NEW_BALANCE, res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_NEW_BALANCE)));
                cv.put(TRANSACTION_CREDIT_ID, res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_CREDIT_ID)));
                whereargs[0] = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TRANSACTION_DATE));
                db.insert(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS, null, cv);
            }
        }
    }
    res.close();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Can you post code on what you have worked.

Comment: Please see the edit above.